# Seria a tag "Javascrip" um erro de digitação do "Javascript"?

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, tags, tags-sinônimas

Existe um tag chamada [`Javascrip`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascrip) que parece ser um erro de digitação de uma tag já existente: [`Javascript`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

A maior parte das perguntas possuem outras tags que são frequentemente associadas ao Javascript, como o JQuery (que é uma biblioteca do Javascript), Ajax e JSON. A tag Javascrip também não possui nenhuma informação.

Isso está correto?
Atualmente possui 7 perguntas com essa tag. *Na real, até pensei em editar manualmente, removendo o `Javascrip` para `Javascript`. Porém resolvi perguntar, afinal deve haver uma outra solução.*

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Aumentar reputação necessária pra se criar tags](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5094/3635)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Obrigado por teres reparado. Corrigi.

Essa tag estava errada e agora que não tem nenhuma pergunta associada a ela deve ser removida pelo sistema.